# chrome.tabs.sendMessage not working with background script and iframe

Tags: javascript, browser-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to send messages from background script of an extension to an iframe that is being rendered on a webpage as part of the contentScript but it is only being received by iframe 4 out of 10 times. The reason for failure is not clear as there are no error logs. Any idea what might be going wrong ?

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent((currentTab) => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
             currentTab.id,
                    {
                      message: "Generic Message",
                    },
                    function () {}
                  );
                });
```

iframe.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {

// Not able to receive here in most of the cases
})
```

I am required to pass messages from background to iframe and vice-versa and that too is highly dynamic in a way that messages from background script would be fired based on events received through websocket connection. Hence, information would be passed back and forth between back and forth between Iframe (rendered inside contentscipt) and background script. So, I also added event listeners in both background and iframe.js and handled only certain cases that need to be handled.

Event listener for background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
  // request.sender is just a property that I added to identify if this event was called from background context or iframe context.
   if (request.sender === "Sender 1") { 
     // Execute this
   } else {
     // Execute this
   }
})
```

So now I have 2 files or contexts and both of them are passing messages and both of them are receiving messages as well.

P.S. I am using manifest v3

Comment: This doesn't compute. The background script runs in the hidden background context, it doesn't have a tab, so chrome.tabs.getCurrent returns `undefined` and your code should never succeed at all. Since it does, the only explanation is that you're loading background.js in some tab, which is wrong or at least misleading. Anyway, you need to send a message inside an event that signals the iframe has loaded e.g. inside chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted. A better approach may be to reverse the direction and send a message from the iframe so the background script responds.

Comment: In this case, the flow of information will be bi-directional i.e. I am required to pass message from background to iframe and vice-versa. Do you think this would be able to suffice our requirements ?

Comment: Yes, you can use sender.tab.id and sender.frameId from onMessage listener parameters in your chrome.tabs.sendMessage call. Alternatively, [open a port](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) from the iframe.

Comment: I already tried opening a port but unfortunately, it did not work. I will try using the other approach that you suggested. Thank you.